# c++ stack overflow due to recursive function how can I improve the data handling

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm tackling a exercise which is designed to cause exactly this problem, of overloading the memory. Pretty much I'm loading various file sizes from 1,000 to 5 million lines of entries like this in a txt file (1 line = 1 entry):

```
SHFIv,aiSdG
PlgNB,bPHoP
ZHWJU,gfwgC
UAygL,Vqvhi
BlyzX,LLbCo
jbvrT,Utblj
...
```

pretty much every entry has 2 values separated by comma, in my code, I separate these values and try to find another matching value, there are always only 2 exactly matching values and each time 1 value is found the other one with which it is paired points to another pair, and so on until the final one gets found.

For example `SHFIv,aiSdG` would point to `aiSdG,YDUVo`.

I know my code is not very efficient, partly due to using recursion, but I could'nt figure out a better way to do the job, so any suggestions on how to possibly improve it to handle larger inputs would be greatly appriciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


template<typename T>
void search_bricks_backwards(string resume, vector<T>& vec, vector<string>& vec2) {
    int index = 0;
    for (const auto& pair : vec) {
        //cout << "iteration " << index << endl;
        if (pair.second == resume) {
            vec2.insert(vec2.begin(), resume);
            cout << "found " << resume << " and " << pair.second << endl;
            search_bricks_backwards(pair.first, vec, vec2);
        }
        if (index + 1 == vec.size()) {
            cout << "end of backward search, exitting..." << endl;


        }
        index++;
    }

}



template<typename T>

void search_bricks(string start, vector<T>& vec, vector<string>& vec2) {
    int index = 0;
    for (const auto& pair : vec) {
        //cout << "iteration " << index << endl;
        if (pair.first == start) {
            vec2.push_back(start);
            cout << "found " << start << " and " << pair.first << endl;
            search_bricks(pair.second, vec, vec2);
        }
        if (index + 1 == vec.size()) {
            //search_bricks_backwards(start, vec, vec2);
           // this also gets called on every recursion rather than just once
           // as I originally intended when the forward iteration gets finished
            

        }
        index++;
    }
    
}

template<typename T> // printing function
void printVectorElements(vector<T>& vec)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "(" << vec.at(i).first << ","
            << vec.at(i).second << ")" << endl ;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

vector<string> split(string s, string delimiter) { // filtering function
    size_t pos_start = 0, pos_end, delim_len = delimiter.length();
    string token;
    vector<string> res;

    while ((pos_end = s.find(delimiter, pos_start)) != string::npos) {
        token = s.substr(pos_start, pos_end - pos_start);
        pos_start = pos_end + delim_len;
        res.push_back(token);
    }

    res.push_back(s.substr(pos_start));
    return res;
}


int main()
{
    vector<pair<string, string>> bricks;
    vector<string> sorted_bricks;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input-pairs-5K.txt"); // transferring data from .txt to a string

    stringstream strStream;
    strStream << inFile.rdbuf(); 
    string str = strStream.str(); 

    
    

    istringstream iss(str);

    for (string line; getline(iss, line); ) 
     // filtering data from string and dividing on ","
    {

        string delimiter = ",";
        string s = line;
        vector<string> v = split(s, delimiter);
        string s1 = v.at(0);
        string s2 = v.at(1);

        bricks.push_back(make_pair(s1, s2));
    }


    search_bricks(bricks[0].second, bricks, sorted_bricks);
    
    
    //printVectorElements(bricks); 
    
    //for (auto i = sorted_bricks.begin(); i != sorted_bricks.end(); ++i)
        //cout << *i << " "; // this is just to check if vectors have data


    
 
}
```

Here is link to the [1k test data](https://pastebin.com/hDYqmYXc) that works for me (only for the search bricks without backwards searching since it triggers on every recursion) again thanks for any suggestions on how to improve or get rid of the recursion. I don't code in c++ often and don't really know how else to tackle this.

Comment: Change to iteration instead (e.g. `while(true)`). The key to iteration is figuring out what information to carry over for each iteration.

Comment: There is an existing non-recursive algorithm for this: topological sort. Look it up.

Comment: Seems like switching from `vector<string>` to `unordered_map<string, string>` to hold the input data would speed things up from `O(N^2)` to `O(N)` (by reducing each lookup from `O(N)` to `O(1)`)

Comment: @user207421 I searched for it, and read a few example code snippets but I'm not sure if the implementation is suitable for my case, from what i found it is used for graphs? [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-program-for-topological-sorting/#:~:text=Topological%20sorting%20for%20Directed%20Acyclic,graph%20is%20not%20a%20DAG.)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes I actually started with unordered_map and unordered_multimap but switched to vector to make the code a bit easier for me to understand since I mostly work with JS objects. I plan to switch the container to a map later on, and maps really seem ideal, however currently I'm looking to rather improve the search functionality to something other than recursion which seems to be the main downfall

Answer (score -1):

Although implementing non-recursive version of your algorithm is canonical solution, if you really need to solve the problem without code modification, you can increase the stack size by modifying compiler option. ~100Mb will be usually sufficient.

In MSVC : `/STACK:commit 104857600`

In gcc  : `--stack, 104857600`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but I am rather looking to improve the code than to just give the program a bigger memory chunk to use :D